# What EOS.IO testnets are available out there?

Tags: testnet

First of all, I know that [I can use local single-node local testnet](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment#4-creating-and-launching-a-single-node-testnet) for development, but I am also interested to know what are other public testnets available, run by a community.

I know, that there is "SuperHero" testnet, what are other public testnets?

## SuperHero

`genesis.json` file

```
{
  "initial_key": "EOS55xgWhiYohaHtFTxcPMorB9MzwBfe3JgUuQEujrurmHLHiXmna",
  "initial_timestamp": "2018-04-06T00:00:00",
  "initial_parameters": {
    "maintenance_interval": 86400,
    "maintenance_skip_slots": 3,
    "maximum_transaction_size": 2048,
    "maximum_block_size": 2048000000,
    "maximum_time_until_expiration": 86400,
    "maximum_producer_count": 1001
  },
  "immutable_parameters": {
    "min_producer_count": 42
  },
  "initial_chain_id": "00000000000000000000000000000000003c332053555045524845524f203c33"
}
```

`config.ini` file

```
# Limits the maximum time (in milliseconds) processing a single get_transactions call. (eosio::account_history_plugin)
get-transactions-time-limit = 3

genesis-json = "/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir/genesis.json"

block-log-dir = "blocks"

max-reversible-block-time = -1
max-pending-transaction-time = -1

http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:9876
# p2p-server-address = <domain or ip address>:9876
access-control-allow-origin = *

#p2p peer address , can be specified mulitple times

##########################################################
p2p-peer-address = eosgreen.uk.to:9875
p2p-peer-address = ctestnet.edenx.io:62071
p2p-peer-address = 54.194.49.21:9875
p2p-peer-address = superhero.cryptolions.io:9885
p2p-peer-address = venom.eoscalgary.com:9877
p2p-peer-address = joker.superhero.eos.roelandp.nl:9873
p2p-peer-address = ctestnet.eosdetroit.com:1339
p2p-peer-address = bp7-d3.eos42.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = superheroes.eosio.africa:9876
p2p-peer-address = 156.38.160.91:9876
p2p-peer-address = 166.70.202.194:9877
p2p-peer-address = 18.188.52.250:9889
p2p-peer-address = ctest.eosnewyork.io:9870
p2p-peer-address = 35.195.161.56:9876
p2p-peer-address = 159.89.197.162:9877
p2p-peer-address = dawn3-seed.tokenika.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = bp.blockgenic.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = 47.52.18.70:9876
p2p-peer-address = 120.27.130.60:9876
p2p-peer-address = ctest.koreos.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = ctestnet.objectcomputing.com:9876
p2p-peer-address = test.eosys.io:9875
p2p-peer-address = bp-test.eosasia.one:9876
p2p-peer-address = 138.68.15.85:9876
p2p-peer-address = 47.88.222.80:9876
p2p-peer-address = 54.233.222.22:9875
p2p-peer-address = 39.108.231.157:9877
p2p-peer-address = ctestnet.eoshenzhen.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = eosbp.enjoyshare.net:9876
p2p-peer-address = bpt1.eosbixin.com:9876
p2p-peer-address = 46.4.253.242:7610
p2p-peer-address = superhero-bp1.eosphere.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = 138.68.238.129:9875
p2p-peer-address = 178.49.174.48:9876
p2p-peer-address = superhero.worbli.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = wonderwoman.eosreal.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = eosbrazil.com:9878
p2p-peer-address = 35.202.41.160:9876
##########################################################

# access-control-allow-headers =
#access-control-allow-credentials = false
mongodb-queue-size = 256

# agent-name = "mynode" # use unique name
allowed-connection = any

log-level-net-plugin = info
max-clients = 25
connection-cleanup-period = 30
network-version-match = 1
sync-fetch-span = 1000
enable-stale-production = false
required-participation = 33

# private-key = ["EOS...",""]
# producer-name = <producername>

# plugin = eosio::producer_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
# plugin = eosio::account_history_plugin
# plugin = eosio::account_history_api_plugin
```

Comment: http://cryptolions.io/

Answer (score 6):

Found this in Telegram (credit goes to Greg Lee):

> Here's a list of community run testnets that I'm aware of:

- SuperHero TestNet: https://github.com/eosgreen/EOS.IO-Community-Testnet-Reactivation
- Jungle TestNet: https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-Jungle-Testnet
- Arrowhead TestNet: https://busy.org/@eluzgin/how-to-join-arrowhead-testnet-for-bp-candidates
- Scholar TestNet: https://github.com/EOS-Nation/EOScholar-Testnet
- EOSIO Net TestNet: https://steemit.com/cryptocurrency/@eostribe/announcing-arrowhead-and-eos-net-testnets

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATED**: 
Jungle is: http://dev.cryptolions.io/

Their github: https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-Jungle-Testnet

Comment: With dawn 4 the jungle monitor is now http://dev.cryptolions.io/

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for making this post. I was planning to aggregate the information into [bp-playbook](https://github.com/eosdetroit/bp-playbook) to make deploying different testnets easy.

**Hack Til Dawn Hackathon Devnet**

`genesis.json` file

```
{
  "initial_timestamp": "2018-03-01T12:00:00.000",
  "initial_key": "EOS8JRondNFTj2hyoNJ26vYDTqtjCUMHGpLBSHU6DFggswkSLR5q8",
  "initial_configuration": {
    "base_per_transaction_net_usage": 100,
    "base_per_transaction_cpu_usage": 500,
    "base_per_action_cpu_usage": 1000,
    "base_setcode_cpu_usage": 2097152,
    "per_signature_cpu_usage": 100000,
    "per_lock_net_usage": 32,
    "context_free_discount_cpu_usage_num": 20,
    "context_free_discount_cpu_usage_den": 100,
    "max_transaction_cpu_usage": 10485760,
    "max_transaction_net_usage": 104857,
    "max_block_cpu_usage": 104857600,
    "target_block_cpu_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_block_net_usage": 1048576,
    "target_block_net_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_lifetime": 3600,
    "max_transaction_exec_time": 0,
    "max_authority_depth": 6,
    "max_inline_depth": 4,
    "max_inline_action_size": 4096,
    "max_generated_transaction_count": 16,
    "max_transaction_delay": 3888000
  },
  "initial_chain_id": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

**Peers**

```
https://hack-til-dawn.eosnation.io
https://hackathon.eosnewyork.io:8889
https://hack-til-dawn.meet.one
http://hack-til-dawn.edenx.io
http://hack-til-dawn.oraclechain.io:8888
http://hack-til-dawn.eosslc.com:7877
https://hackathon.eoscalgary.io
http://hacktildawn.eosphere.io:8888
https://hack-til-dawn.eoscannon.io
https://hacktildawn.eosdetroit.com
```

Comment: are you connected to this testnet? I have some problem to connect. My logs: https://gist.github.com/noisy/efdf592f33701d5a9b2965c792eca3a4

BTW, I am on chat: 
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77214/eos-io

Answer (score 2):

If you want to launch a mode to work locally, you should try github.com/eoscanada/eos-bios .. it's a command line tool, you copy the config and boot with a single command:

```
 eos-bios boot --single
```

You can use that tool to join the staged launches that are happening, which hopefully lead to the mainnet. They are being orchestrated in the Telegram channel referenced in that repository.

There is a series of videos we're putting out to explain how the process works, start here: https://youtu.be/8aNZ_ZnKS-A

Comment: As of today, we are at stage3, prepping for stage4 on dawn4.